Integrating FileMaker Pro 24 with ServiceM8: How to Handle Email Threading for Client Replies within the job number?
I am developing a FileMaker Pro 24 application that integrates with ServiceM8 to fill gaps in functionality that ServiceM8 does not natively support. One critical need is the ability for emails sent from ServiceM8 to be pulled into FileMaker Pro, allowing me to reply directly to clients from within FileMaker. However, I am encountering issues with how ServiceM8 defines or generates email thread IDs (UUIDs), which makes it difficult to maintain email threading within the job context. I have studied the ServiceM8 API thoroughly, but I cannot identify a reliable way to decode or track these UUID conventions for email threads.
Studied ServiceM8's API and guidelines on email threading.
Attempted various approaches to track and match UUIDs between emails and job records within FileMaker.
Reached out to ServiceM8 support, who referred me here to Stack Overflow for potential solutions.
What I Expected:
I expected to find a clear method within ServiceM8’s API documentation for handling email thread identification or UUID generation so that replies to emails from within FileMaker would thread correctly back to the original client conversation.

I am not familiar with ServiceM8 APIs, but usually the thread ID is included in the source text of the email. You can read the source of the email and then store the thread ID in FileMaker for linking with the other emails with the same id.
